# datatype to store a delimited list

Tags: mysql

I want to store strings like this

> "1,5,6,7,9,45,20,45,78,81..."

- Numbers can't be negative or decimal and vary form 0-+-200
- Numbers are separated by ','
- List can be 0-150 items long max.

What Datatype should I use for the column that will hold these strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking to store is referred to as denormalized data.  MySQL has some functionality specifically for dealing with this, but the best approach is to store a single value per row, like:

```
id  |  value
---------------
1   |  1
1   |  5
1   |  6
1   |  7
```

..and so on.  Because a comma separated list:

1. is difficult to look for specific values within it
2. can be generated using [MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

   ```
     SELECT t.id, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(t.value)
       FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY t.id
   ```

Here's the CREATE TABLE statement for the table setup I recommend:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`list_values`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`list_values` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `val` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`val`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The primary key being both columns ensures you can't have duplicates for a set - remove it if that's not true for the data you want to store.

### List can be 0-150 items long max.

You'll need to use [a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to enforce that business rule.

Comment: Do you, like, precompute answers and wait for someone to ask a question that's in the dictionary?  Because you are *fast*...

Comment: @Justin K: Hah - No but I should look into it.  I had to start my VM to get the CREATE TABLE statement after creating the table (and forgetting the primary key definition - had to go back...), while getting the MySQL documentation link in another Firefox tab.  Quassnoi would've done it in half the time, and written an article about it before I'd finish.

Answer (score 0):

OMG Ponies' response is the 'traditional' SQL-oriented response but does not really address the question. Postgres has built-in list types for columns. If you do as I have and more-or-less given up on building applications entirely in SQL, then in Python, for example, you can pickle your list into a string, store it in the varchar column in MySQL and then unpickle it on retreival before using it. Using pickle ensures that quoted strings and other peculiarities in the list will be taken care of correctly.